# Convert php string to array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string something like this:

'1,2'

I want to convert it to this format:

```
Array
(
[0] => (
       [0] => Array
              (
              [username] => 1
              )
       [1] => Array
              (
              [username] => 2
              )
        )
)
```

I am trying to do this in a PHP script and used explode to convert the string to an array. But how do I create it to the desired format?

Comment: This is not hard to do. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string into values and then [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to create the output array from each of those values:

```
$str = '1,2';
print_r(array_map(function ($v) { return array('username' => $v); }, explode(',', $str)));
```

Output

```
Array
(
       [0] => Array
              (
              [username] => 1
              )
       [1] => Array
              (
              [username] => 2
              )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fhEHB)